# How would you add gutters here?

Tags: water-damage, gutters, flashing

Our home was built with a fascia/eave that directs water right onto our deck near the slider. I want to find some way to install a gutter or something to redirect water elsewhere. Is there any good way to handle this?

[image: problem area]

Comment: Best choice for the downspouts is angle down to the outside corner and then down the corner.  Look for paintable downspouts to try to match the wall colour.

Comment: This is really an aesthetics question. A downspout running vertical just to the left of the door and punching through the deck seems as good as it gets. With the image truncating whatever is out of frame to the left, however, I'm not absolutely sure. Based on the area of contributing roof, I would try to size a small downspout (assuming that there isn't a tree dumping leaves up there to clog a small downspout)

Comment: @crip, I think even white downspouts wouldn't look out of place, with the white siding corner posts.  Hard to see what the deck looks like with the limited context, but hopefully that's just a mat (that can be perforated by a downspout) going all the way across, and not some kind of solid covering material.

Comment: @Huesmann The deck is wood and would have to be drilled through with a hole saw to have a gutter run through it. Unfortunately, below it is another deck on the first level (we're standing on floor 2 right here). So I would have to punch through 2 decks and then routing it under the bottom floor deck would be difficult since it's ground level.